# How to iterate over array objects inside of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop

I have `vs.selectedTags` which is an array with 3 objects.

In my for loop which will run 3 times, I need to make 3 API calls to get the tickers data for each object which I'm able too.

My problem comes when I try to assign those tickers to each `vs.selectedTags[i].tickers` object in the array.

It can't iterate over the `i` inside of the `ApiFactory` call. `i` becomes 3, and I have to cheat by using `[i-1]` to stop it from erroring out. However `i` still stays stuck at `2` so it always saves the last tickers data to **all** the items in my `vs.selectedTags` array.

```
var vs = $scope;

for (var i = 0; i < vs.selectedTags.length; i++) {

    console.log(i);

    vs.selectedTags[i].tickers = '';

    console.log(vs.selectedTags[i].tickers);

    ApiFactory.getTagData(vs.chosenTicker, vs.selectedTags[i].term_id).then(function(data) {

        // console.log(data.data.ticker_tag);
        console.log(data.data.ticker_tag.tickers);

        console.log(i-1);

        // console.log(vs.selectedTags[0]);

        // How would you properly iterate [0 - 1 - 2] here?
        vs.selectedTags[i-1].tickers = data.data.ticker_tag.tickers;

        console.log(vs.selectedTags[i-1]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a closure / new scope, as the `ApiFactory.getTagData` function is asynchronous

```
for (var i = 0; i < vs.selectedTags.length; i++) {
    (function(j) {

        vs.selectedTags[j].tickers = '';

        ApiFactory.getTagData(vs.chosenTicker, vs.selectedTags[j].term_id).then(function(data) {

             vs.selectedTags[j].tickers = data.data.ticker_tag.tickers;
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: All it takes is a function, and an IIFE is a function and it creates a new scope. Some like it, some think it's better to have to code in a seperate function, I think it depends, if it's just simple code inside a loop just wrapping it in an IIFE makes it easier for me to read than moving code out.

Answer (score 1):

if you put the stuff inside of your for loop in a separate function it will fix your closure issue. so:

```
var bob = function(i){
    console.log(i);

    vs.selectedTags[i].tickers = '';

    console.log(vs.selectedTags[i].tickers);

    ApiFactory.getTagData(vs.chosenTicker, vs.selectedTags[i].term_id).then(function(data) {

        // console.log(data.data.ticker_tag);
        console.log(data.data.ticker_tag.tickers);

        console.log(i);

        // console.log(vs.selectedTags[0]);

        // How would you properly iterate [0 - 1 - 2] here?
        vs.selectedTags[i].tickers = data.data.ticker_tag.tickers;

        console.log(vs.selectedTags[i]);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < vs.selectedTags.length; i++) {
    bob(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this also works :) +1 Sigh, yeah this is probably where I would have finally ended up at... I like @adeneo's neat solution tho